# PreLog Blocks in frontier ethereum pallet on_initialize hook

Tags: frontier, digest

```rust
fn on_initialize(_: T::BlockNumber) -> Weight {
            let mut weight = T::SystemWeightInfo::kill_storage(1);

            // If the digest contain an existing ethereum block(encoded as PreLog), If contains,
            // execute the imported block firstly and disable transact dispatch function.
            if let Ok(log) = fp_consensus::find_pre_log(&frame_system::Pallet::<T>::digest()) {
                let PreLog::Block(block) = log;

                for transaction in block.transactions {
                    let source = Self::recover_signer(&transaction).expect(
                        "pre-block transaction signature invalid; the block cannot be built",
                    );

                    Self::validate_transaction_in_block(source, &transaction).expect(
                        "pre-block transaction verification failed; the block cannot be built",
                    );
                    let r = Self::apply_validated_transaction(source, transaction)
                        .expect("pre-block apply transaction failed; the block cannot be built");

                    weight = weight.saturating_add(r.actual_weight.unwrap_or_default());
                }
            }
```

This hook is part of the ethereum pallet defined in Frontier. I understand that in the wrapped block model, communication between the runtime and the node can be achieved through digest. It's used by the `on_finalize` hook to pass data about the inner block, in so the client can keep a mapping of inner to outer block up to date.

The code I quoted seems to check that the provided block is valid and then execute the transactions it contains.
My problem is that I don't understand under which conditions exactly a block would be provided to the runtime by a `PreRuntime` `DigestItem`.

Also the logging of the block in the `Digest` in the `on_finalize` hook is disabled when a `PreRuntime` block had been found. But I cannot see how having a `PreRuntime` block prevent from more transactions to be added to the block through regular extrinsic execution.

Aslo, it seems to go against the 1-1 equivalence between wrapped and wrapper blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PreLog` digest is not actually used in the frontier runtime by now. It's only reserved for [some reasons](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/pull/1014#issuecomment-1457991446).

Comment: How do you speed up the syncing while using this?
I mean, you don't want to wait the full block time each time you are importing a new block. You want to run the `on_initialize` and then immediately the `on_finalize`, without waiting for any transaction to come